# Is it possible to unit test iot edge code?

Tags: unit-testing, azure-iot-edge

What are best practices for testing iot edge code?

Actually there are several questions, i'm struggling now

1. How to unit test iot edge module code?
2. How to test the code on a device esp. message routing etc.?

Struggling with this topics. I have angular backbground - testing is a concept by design.

It seems for me that testing is not a key concept on iot devices.

Does somebody has experince on that?

Comment: I hope these links provide some help or idea to get started :[Unit testing in IoT edge Modules?](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/issues/1380), [Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Test](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge/tree/master/edge-hub/test/Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Hub.Core.Test) , [iot-edge-unit-test](https://github.com/VSChina/iot-edge-unit-test) , [Azure IoT Edge Testing Utility](https://hub.docker.com/_/microsoft-azureiotedge-testing-utility), [IoTEdge Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-iot-edge-support-in-azure-devops-project-and-azure-pipelines/)

Comment: @SatishBoddu-MSFT to be honest, not really

Comment: I completely understand, Sorry for the inconvenience caused. I am checking this with my team on how can we help you with this query, please stay tuned.